# What is the easiest way to squash commits using Egit?

Tags: git, github, version-control

What is the easiest way to squash commits using Egit? I would really like to do it using Egit(Git plugin for Eclipse). I am already have a small idea on how to do it from a command prompt, it is a pain.

1. is it ok to squash changes if I have pushed the commits to my remote github repository (this repository is only used by me)?
2. If some of my team mates have made commits in between my commits , Can I squash them too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In History tab select all commits you want to squash. Then right-click the selected commits and from the context menu select Modify --> Squash.

Comment: To get to the correct "History" tab, right click on your project and select Team -> Show in History.  Tip: since the selected commits must be consecutive, select the first commit to be squashed and then use shift-click to select the last commit to be squashed.

Comment: Then, you need to actually Push your squashed commits, either from the Package Explorer --> Your top level project (right click) --> Team --> Push HEAD or from Git Repositories --> Your Repo (right click)--> Push HEAD (or Push to Gerrit; if you're using it).

Answer (score 1):

Open Git History Perspective then select the commits which need to be squashed, right click--> modify --> squash.
 This will take to to rebase , open Git Staging Perspective resolve any conflicts and commit

Answer (score 0):

Squashing with egit.

Go to Team--> Show in History-->Here you will be able to see all commits, now select all the commits which you want to squash(you cal also select the commits made by your team) and then right click, you should be able to see "Modify" click it and hit squash button and enter required commit message.

As you have a new commit we need to push it now...Team--push--"**make sure to check this box** "force overwrite branch in remote if it exists and has diverged"   click finish
When you pulll the master you will get the merge conflicts replace those files with your recent commit files and stage them and enter the commit message and accordingly push it.

Sit back and relax now. :D

Answers for yor 2 questions:
is it ok to squash changes if I have pushed the commits to my remote github repository (this repository is only used by me)?
        Yes you can squash commits after pushing to remote.

If some of my team mates have made commits in between my commits , Can I squash them too?
        Yes you can squash the changes made by your team members.